# in my code i unable to get image name , or image preview in wordpress setting page please give some solution

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

This is my code here I can't get image name to store in a database, and I can't see image preview also when it selected.

```
 add_action('admin_footer',array(&$this,'media_selector_print_scripts'));

    public function media_selector_settings_page_callback(){
        if(isset($_POST['submit_image_selector'])&& 
        isset($_POST['image_attachment_id'])):
           update_option('media_selector_attachment_id',absint($_POST['image_attachment_id']));
        endif;
        wp_enqueue_media();
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $category = $_POST['category'];
            $type = $_POST['type'];
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $description = $_POST['description'];
            $img_path = get_option('media_selector_attachment_id');

            $insert_data = new insert_Data();
            $insert_data-
        >insert_table_data($category,$type,$name,$description,$img_path);
        }
        ?>
```

WordPress setting page design HTML

```
<h1>Plugin page</h1>

<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <br><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="category" placeholder="category"/><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="type" placeholder="type"/><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name"/><br><br>
    <textarea name="description" placeholder="description"></textarea>
   <br><br>
    <div class="img-preview-wrapper">
        <img id="img-preview" src="<?php echo 
  wp_get_attachment_url(get_option('media_selector_attachment_id')); ?>" 
   height="100px"/>
    </div>
    <input id="upload_image_button" type="button" class="button" value="<?php _e('Upload image'); ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="image_attachment_id" id="image_attachment_id" value="<?php echo get_option('media_selector_attachment_id'); ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" class="button-primary"/>
</form>

<?php
```

}

this is jquery script

```
public function media_selector_print_scripts(){
$my_saved_attachment_post_id = get_option('media_selector_attachment_id',0);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        //uploading files
        var file_frame;
        var wp_media_post_id = wp.media.model.settings.post.id;//store the old id
        var set_to_post_id = <?php echo $my_saved_attachment_post_id;?>;

        jQuery('#upload_image_button').on('click', function (event) {

            event.preventDefault();

            //if the media frame already exists, reopen it
            if (file_frame){
                //set the post id to what we want
                file_frame.uploader.uploader.param('post_id', set_to_post_id);
                //open frame
                file_frame.open();
                return;
            } else {
                wp.media.model.settings.post.id = set_to_post_id;
            }
            //create the media frame
            file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
                title: 'Select a image to upload',
                button: {
                    text: 'Use this image',
                },
                multiple:false
            });
            file_frame.on('select', function () {
                attachment = 
           file_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
   $('#image-preview').attr('src',attachment.url).css('width','auto');
                $('#image-attachment-id').val(attachment.id);

                wp.media.model.settings.post.id = wp_media_post_id;
            });
            file_frame.open();
        });
        jQuery('a.add-media').on('click', function(){
            wp.media.model.settings.post.id = wp_media_post_id;
        });
    });
</script>
<?php
```

}

This is my code here I can't get image name to store in a database, and I can't see image preview also when it selected.This is my code here I can't get image name to store in a database, and I can't see image preview also when it selected.This is my code here I can't get image name to store in a database, and I can't see image preview also when it selected.

Comment: Repeating _“This is my code here I can't get image name to store in a database, and I can't see image preview also when it selected.”_ four times doesn’t make your question any clearer. What have you done so far to _debug_ this?

Comment: actually, I purposefully did that, when I posting my question it was showing error, so I did that

Comment: What error? Something saying that it looks like you posted too much code with too little explanation? In such a case, you should provide a _better_ explanation, not just blow the text content ratio up by repeating yourself via copy&paste ...

Comment: thanks for the information, I'll make sure it will not repeat again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *php* file you have a check for `isset($_POST['submit_image_selector'])` but I don't see such a field in *html*.
Try to replace it with `isset($_POST['submit'])`.

Comment: thanks for solution ya I did replace "isset($_POST['submit_image_selector'])" to "isset($_POST['submit'])" but not use

Comment: You should also replace `$('#image-attachment-id')` with `$('#image_attachment_id')`